# How to retrive all the tags from Jquery Tag-it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

I am using jQuery Tagit plugin with autocomplete feature in order to add tags to my website.

Now I want to retrieve all the the tags entered by the user in the input field ( in JSON form )
so that I can save all entered tags by the user in to another DB.

Any idea how to go ahead with it?

Comment: One would thing there must be a function for that. Have you tried to find it? https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: Yes i tried looking but couldnt find any method.

Comment: I am using the below code to :-  $("#demo2GetTags").click(function() {
   showTags($("#tags").tagit("tags"))
  });

  function showTags(tags) {
   console.log(tags);
   var string = "Tags (label : value)\r\n";
   string += "--------\r\n";
   for ( var i in tags)
    string += tags[i].label + " : " + tags[i].value + "\r\n";
   alert(string);
  }